# Was Krishnadeva Raya initiated into Vaishnavism?

Tags: vaishnavism

Krishnadeva Raya was the greatest ruler of the Vijayanagara empire. Wikipedia says that he was initiated into Vaishnavism.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krishnadevaraya

> Krishna Deva Raya was formally initiated into the Vaishnava Sampradaya by Tathacharya

I have two questions -

1. Is it really true that Krishnadevaraya was initiated into Vaishnavism?
2. If true, was he initiated into Sri Vaishnavism or Madhva Vaishnavism?

Comment: This blog claims he was initiated into Sri Vaishnavism: https://www.google.com/amp/s/4krsna.wordpress.com/2008/07/26/sri-krishna-deva-raya/amp/

Comment: @Surya The site interestingly calls Vyasatirtha as his guru. Now Vyasatirtha was a Madhva vaishnava.

Answer (score 2):

The "Tathacharya" referred to in the Wikipedia link is a well known acharya in the Srivaishnava Sampradaya. I am not aware of an explicit mention of Krishnadevaraya being initiated into Srivaishnavism but both Ahobila and Parakala Mutts are known to have had a long association with the Vijayanagar empire in general and Krishnadevaraya in particular (but that by itself is insufficient evidence). If I find a source, I will update this answer.

That said, **that Krishnadevaraya's personal affiliation was towards Srivaishnavism is unambiguously evident from his work "Amuktamalyada"** - a telugu rendering of the story of Andal who is one of the 12 Azhvars.

I will cite two scholarly works that establish this:

According to [Velcheru Narayana Rao et.al.,](http://utilisateurs.linguist.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~chevilla/FestSchrift/VeShSa_5a.pdf) among the characters referenced in the Amuktamalyada, other than Andal, we find references to Periyazhvar (aka Vishnuchitta) and Yamunacharya (pre-Ramanujan acharya of the Srivaishnava Sampradaya). More interestingly, the authors note that Krishnadevaraya incorporated Srivaishnava values into governing principles.

> in tone. A distinction is drawn -- perhaps for the first time in South
>   India -- between the king as individual, with his individual
>   inclinations and exigencies, and kingship as institution (which has to
>   go on at all costs). **A basis for stable kingship is elaborated around
>   Srivaishnava, trans-local values**, with a yogic colouring, an aesthetic
>   component (expressed through music), and strong themes of personal,
>   non-ascriptive loyalty.

and

> Krishnadevaraya eschews the standard solution, namely the resort to
>   purāṇic and dharmaśāstric normative language regarding an alliance
>   between Brahmins and Kshatriyas. Instead, his preference is markedly
>   for yogic and renunciatory themes that are at the same time strongly
>   and paradoxically **allied to a Srivaishnava idiom** rooted in the idea of
>   bhoga (enjoyment) – a theme to which we shall return below

and in the conclusion

> It may be argued that the rājanīti section of the Āmukta-mālyada
>   embodies a paradox, since it gives pragmatic advice on rulership while
>   at the same time being framed in a text where the ideal that is
>   insisted upon is one of renunciation. The paradox is however easily
>   resolved. **For the central thrust of the Srivaishnava political
>   theology in which this advice comes embedded** is that it is necessary
>   to separate rulership as a social function – which is not merely
>   desirable but essential for the world to cohere -- from the personal
>   salvation of the ruler. It is understood that at some moment or other
>   in his life, the king will wish to escape the bonds of his royal life
>   and become a renouncer. The text does not suggest otherwise, and quite
>   on the contrary, expresses its unbounded admiration for such rulers.
>   But the view is clearly that renunciation is not a solution to the
>   problems of kingship, only to the problems of the king as individual.
>   We are not quite in the realm of the ‘two bodies’ of the king
>   developed by Kantorowicz, **but what is obviously being proposed here is
>   a view where Srivaishnava this-worldliness plays a central role in
>   protecting the king from renunciatory excess.**

In his PhD dissertation submitted at UC Berkeley, ["The Āmuktamālyada of Kṛṣṇadevarāya, Language, Power & Devotion in Sixteenth Century South India"](http://digitalassets.lib.berkeley.edu/etd/ucb/text/Reddy_berkeley_0028E_11659.pdf), Srinivas G. Reddy says:

> **Kṛṣṇadevarāya was thoroughly steeped in the Śrīvaiṣṇava tradition and
>   almost every poem in his great work exudes a sense of his personal
>   devotion.** The famous avatārika padyam or invocation verse to his
>   iṣṭa-devata Lord Vĕṅkateśvara is also interpreted as a salutation to
>   Kulaśekhara Āḻvār in his aṁśa-avatāra as the Kaustubha gem. The
>   invocatory decad that ends with an explicit poem about the saints
>   (quoted above), is in fact a sustained evocation of their divine
>   status, and their central importance in the poet‟s heart.